# Does suiteacript 2.0 support Template literals?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Does Suiteacript 2.0 support Template literals?
``` var url = `www.google.co.il/${mystring}`

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use them is you use SuiteScript 2.1

Comment: This is the correct answer, declare 2.1 on your script

Comment: https://ursuscode.com/netsuite-tips/suitescript-2-1-features/

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't support literals netsuite Javascript version but you can use TypeScript with Netsuite 2.0 there you have the option of string literals.